# Как эффективно подсчитать количество true в двухмерном массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы, поиск

Дан массив типа `boolean`:

```java
static boolean[][] arr = {
        {false, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false, false},
        {true, true, true, true, true}};
```

**Обращаться к массиву на прямую нельзя, только через заранее подготовленный метод `hasTrue`**, который принимает начальную и конечную точки подмассива, из вышеприведенного массива, и возвращает `boolean` - содержит ли этот подмассив `true` хотябы один раз.

```java
boolean hasTrue(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
```

Например, если нужно проверить диапазон от `(0,0)` до `(1,1)`, вызваем метод `hasTrue(0,0,1,1)`, он возвращает `true`, поскольку в точке `(1,0)` значение `true`. Либо можно указать только одну точку, например, `hasTrue(0,0,0,0)` - возвращет `false`.

Нужно реализовать метод, который подсчитывает количество `true` в заданном диапазоне, и который **должен использовать метод `hasTrue`**.

```java
int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
```

Один из вариантов решения - пройтись *брут форсом* по всему диапазону и подсчитать количество элементов `true`, но в таком случае *временная сложность алгоритма* будет `O(n*m)`.

Другой вариант решения, над которым я думаю, - это реализовать рекурсивный метод, который передает целиком весь массив в метод `hasTrue`, и если весь массив возвращает `false`, тогда не нужно будет обходить все его элементы, а просто вернуть `0`. Временная сложность будет `O(1)`.

Если метод вернет `true`, тогда делим массив пополам и обдаратываем части, и так далее считаем количество. Нужна помощь в реализации второго варианта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку *обращаться к массиву на прямую нельзя*, а только через метод `hasTrue`, то можно создать рекурсивный метод `countTrues`, с использованием подхода *половинного деления*. Для итераций можно использовать [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```java
static boolean[][] arr = {
        {false, false, true, false, true},
        {true, false, true, false, false},
        {false, true, false, false, false},
        {false, false, false, false, false},
        {true, true, true, true, true}};
```

```java
static boolean hasTrue(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    // синтаксис некорректен
    if (startX > endX || startY > endY)
        return false;

    return IntStream
        // обходим указанный
        // диапазон строк
        .rangeClosed(startX, endX)
        // получаем строку по индексу
        // Stream<boolean[]>
        .mapToObj(i -> arr[i])
        // хотя бы одно вхождение
        // true в любой строке
        .anyMatch(row -> IntStream
            // обходим указанный
            // диапазон элементов
            .rangeClosed(startY, endY)
            // хотя бы одно вхождение
            // true в этой строке
            .anyMatch(j -> row[j]));
}
```

```java
static int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    // ни одного вхождения true на этой итерации
    if (!hasTrue(startX, startY, endX, endY))
        return 0;

    // рекурсивные вызовы
    int lengthX = endX - startX;
    int lengthY = endY - startY;
    int middleX = lengthX / 2;
    int middleY = lengthY / 2;
    if (lengthX > 0 || lengthY > 0)
        return IntStream
            // если 'lengthX > 0', тогда две итерации X: от начала до
            // середины и от середины до конца, иначе одна итерация
            .rangeClosed(0, lengthX > 0 ? 1 : 0)
            .map(i -> i == 0 ? 0 : middleX + 1)
            .map(i -> IntStream
                // если 'lengthY > 0', тогда две итерации Y: от начала до
                // середины и от середины до конца, иначе одна итерация
                .rangeClosed(0, lengthY > 0 ? 1 : 0)
                .map(j -> j == 0 ? 0 : middleY + 1)
                // рекурсивные вызовы, если нужно, для квадратов:
                // верхний-левый, верхний-правый, нижний-левый, нижний-правый
                .map(j -> countTrues(startX + i, startY + j,
                    i == 0 ? startX + middleX : endX,
                    j == 0 ? startY + middleY : endY))
                .sum())
            .sum();

    // если дошли до этой точки, эта точка - есть true
    return 1;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hasTrue(1, 1, 3, 3)); // true
    System.out.println(countTrues(1, 1, 3, 3)); // 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще во втором варианте, функция `countTrues` всегда будет обращаться к элементам матрицы 25 раз, но это если ни одного `true` нет. Иначе обращений будет больше, что уже намного хуже чем обычный проход по всей матрице.

Но если нужно, то вот пример функции `countTrues`, которая рекурсивно делит матрицу на 4 подматрицы каждый раз проверяя есть ли в ней `true`:

```
public static int countTrues(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY){
    //Проверяем на наличие true
    if (!hasTrue(startX, startY, endX, endY))
        return 0;
    //Если рассматриваем строку, столбец или один элемент, 
    //то просто обычным циклом подсчитаем кол-во true
    if (startX == endX || startY == endY)
        return calcCount(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    int count = 0;
    int tEndX = (startX + endX) / 2;
    int tEndY = (startY + endY) / 2;
    //Подсчитываем true в левой верхней части матрицы
    count += countTrues(startX, startY, tEndX, tEndY);
    //В правой нижней части
    count += countTrues(tEndX + 1, tEndY + 1, endX, endY);
    //В левой нижней
    count += countTrues(startX, tEndY + 1, tEndX, endY);
    //И в правой нижней части
    count += countTrues(tEndX + 1, startY, endX, tEndY);
    return count;
}
```

Код простой функции `calcCount`:

```
public static int calcCount(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = startY; i <= endY; ++i)
        for (int j = startX; j <= endX; ++j)
            if (arr[i][j]) 
                ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Полный [код](https://ideone.com/IXwUqN)